# Having a string how to get its contents from first `/r/n/r/n` until 2 lines from string end?

Tags: c++, string

I try to create simple file upload service in C++. I get all user request body as one big string. User can upload any type of data. I need to get only user file contents from request boby string.

so for example now I have next code working with my service API provider:

```
std::cout << "Request body: " << request->body << std::endl << "Request size: " <<  request->body.length() << std::endl;
```

and this would print as:

```
Request body: ------WebKitFormBoundaryAZlJcLinxYi6OCzX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile"; filename="crossdomain.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

я╗┐<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-
omain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
------WebKitFormBoundaryAZlJcLinxYi6OCzX--

Request size: 411
```

So I need to get from request->body (which is string) all data from first `/r/n/r/n` until last line -2 lines. How to do such thing with string in C++?

Comment: I'd recommend writing code to do it.  Seems like scissors and paste would be a long road.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+string+search

Comment: @Tom: those dashes look like seeds, maybe a low cost pigeon cluster could be used for this task: http://www.google.com/technology/pigeonrank.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant approach, but one option would be to do something like this:

```
std::string contents = /* ... get the string ... */

/* Locate the start point. */
unsigned startPoint = contents.find("\r\n\r\n");
if (startPoint == string::npos) throw runtime_error("Malformed string.");

/* Locate the end point by finding the last newline, then backing up
 * to the newline before that.
 */
unsigned endPoint = contents.rfind('\n');
if (endPoint == string::npos || endPoint == 0) throw runtime_error("Malformed string.");
endPoint = contents.rfind('\n', endPoint - 1);
if (endPoint == string::npos) throw runtime_error("Malformed string.");

/* Hand back that slice of the string. */
return std::string(contents.begin() + startPoint, contents.begin() + endPoint);
```

Comment: This answers the question, but the correct approach would be to get the terminator from the "Request body:" line.

Comment: The first `if (endPoint == string::npos || endPoint == 0)` is unnecessary as the string definitely contains `\r\n`. And the second `if` also :) It's possible that string contains just `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: result will contain an extra `\r`

Comment: @Ben Voigt- I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for that. This page has some nice c++ examples: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/libg++_19.html